# Helm Chart error upgrading to GKE with auth

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am installing the new gke-gcloud-auth-plugin in the cloud-sdk stage before in the helm:latest stage

and when I run helm upgrade I get this error

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://34.70.20.65/version": getting credentials: exec: executable gke-gcloud-auth-plugin not found
```

But in the previous stage I was able to

```
 - export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
- export KUBECONFIG=kube.conf && gcloud container clusters get-credentials $GCP_CLUSTER --zone $GCP_LOCATION --project $GCP_PROJECT
```

and in the helm deploy stage i am running

```
- helm version
- export KUBECONFIG=kube.conf
- helm upgrade $HELM_CHART_NAME ./chart --install --values=./chart/$ENVIRONMENT.yaml --namespace $KUBE_NAMESPACE
```

is there a way to bypass the error?

Comment: How are you installing the  gke-gcloud-auth-plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, I suggest you use this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke) which recommends trying to reinstall the plugin again, because the plugin was not installed correctly.